# All tabs are showing, but I would like only one tab to show at any given time

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Could someone take a look at the javascript below?

I would like to create 3 tabs, with only one tab showing at any given time, when selected.

Right now, when testing the below code, the 3 tabs show by default under each other (as opposed to only one) and only once a tab is selected, the other tabs are hidden.

```
<div class="tab">

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'General')">
    <span size="4" style="font-size: small;">
      <span color="grey" style="color: grey;">
        <b>General</b>
      </span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Product Specifications')">
    <span size="4" style="font-size: small;">
      <span color="grey" style="color: grey;">
        <b>Product Specifications</b>
      </span>
    </span>
  </button>

  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Guarantee')">
    <span size="4" style="font-size: small;">
      <span color="grey" style="color: grey;">
        <b>Guarantee</b>
      </span>
    </span>
  </button>

</div>

<div id="General" class="tabcontent">
  CONTENT
</div>

<div id="Product Specifications" class="tabcontent">
  CONTENT
</div>

<div id="Guarantee" class="tabcontent">
  CONTENT
</div>

<script>// <![CDATA[
  function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 by default we are showing first tab, on click of the other tabs data will be shown accordingly, working demo is shown below
```

```html
Could someone take a look at the javascript below? I would like to create 3 tabs, with only one tab showing at any given time, when selected. Right now, when testing the below code, the 3 tabs show by default under each other (as opposed to only one)
and only once a tab is selected, the other tabs are hidden.
<style>

</style>
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')">London</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
</div>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>


<div id="General" class="tabcontent">
  General CONTENT
</div>

<div id="Product Specifications" class="tabcontent">
  Product Specifications CONTENT
</div>

<div id="Guarantee" class="tabcontent">
  GuaranteeCONTENT
</div>

<script>
  // Get all elements with class="tabcontent" and hide them
  var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 1; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  // <![CDATA[
  function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;

    var tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
      tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
      tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
  }
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. This is helpful.  However, is there a way to let the first tab show by default?  and only hide the content of the second and third tab, until clicked. But when clicked, only the content of the selected tab should show.

Comment: i have edited the answer as per your requirement(showing first tab on load)